# How to automatically delete stopped environments in Gitlab CI/CD

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

We host our review apps in S3. There's option to auto stop environments in a certain time period. However, is there any setting to automatically delete those stopped environments that appear under Deployments > Environments > Stopped?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no native functionality in Gitlab that I am aware of to delete stopped environments, but you can schedule a gitlab pipeline which runs in a certain inverval and deletes stopped environments via the gitlab api.

In this pipeline you can get a [list](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/environments.html#list-environments) of all environments of a repository in the stopped state and then you can iterate over this list and [delete](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/environments.html#delete-an-environment) the stopped environment via id.

An example pipeline can look like the following:

```
stages:
  - delete

delete:environments:
  stage: delete
  variables:
    GITLAB_BASE_URL: https://gitlab.example.url.com
    GITLAB_NAMESPACE: foo
    GITLAB_GROUP: mygroup
  script:
    - |
      echo "[INFO] - $(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') - Getting all stopped environments in project ${GITLAB_NAMESPACE}:${GITLAB_GROUP}:${GITLAB_PROJECT}"
      environment_ids=$(curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:${GITLAB_API_ACCESS_TOKEN}" --silent POST --get \
        "${GITLAB_BASE_URL}/api/v4/projects/${GITLAB_NAMESPACE}%2F${GITLAB_GROUP}%2F${GITLAB_PROJECT}/environments" \
        --data states=stopped | jq ' .[].id')

      if [[ -z ${environment_ids} ]]; then
        echo "[INFO] - $(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') - No stopped environments to delete."
        exit 0
      fi

      for id in ${environment_ids};
      do
        echo "[INFO] - $(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') - Deleting environment ${id} in project ${GITLAB_PROJECT}"
        curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:${GITLAB_API_ACCESS_TOKEN}" --silent --request DELETE \
          "${GITLAB_BASE_URL}/api/v4/projects/${GITLAB_NAMESPACE}%2F${GITLAB_GROUP}%2F${GITLAB_PROJECT}/environments/${id}"
        sleep 1
      done
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - GITLAB_PROJECT: [repo1, repo2, repo3]
```

Comment: Thanks and appreciate the answer. Shame there's no native way to do this. Would you know if these stopped environments are automatically expire after a period? or do these need to be cleaned up manually

Comment: @TalalNajam as far as I know there's no automatic expiration.
I'm currently building a simple script for a client that cleans up old environments that're lying around since over three years. Gitlab provides an API endpoint for this, which makes it relatively nice to automate: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/#delete-an-environment